# What's the difference between 'class A:' and 'class A(object):' in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-3.x

What's the difference between

```
class A:
    pass
```

and

```
class B(object):
    pass
```

? For some reason, in methods I can't use `super(A, self)` but `super(B, self)` works great. I guess there's no such peculiarity in Py3k :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is an old style class. The second is a new-style class. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance for a good discussion of the difference. `super()` only works with new-style classes. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Hm, so that's why people have adviced me to learn Python2 first.. :))) I'll accept this ASAP

Answer (score 6):

In 2.x, the latter creates a [new-style class](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/). In 3.x, both have the same effect since old-style classes have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Class B is a new style class http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/

Answer (score 1):

As already said the second case creates a new-style class, while the first one creates an old-style class(deprecated!).

New-style classes where created to remove the limitation of the old-styles: old-style classes could not inherit from built-in types.
With new-style classes you can inherit from built-in types; in fact all built-in types derive from "object":

```
>>> list.__mro__
(<type 'list'>, <type 'object'>)
```